# Apollo/React: state management for async page components that get unmounted on logout?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, apollo, apollo-client

The picture below shows the /library endpoint of an Apollo / React App with this structure:

```
   <App/>
     <Home/>
     <Library/> // Only renders if a user is logged in
```

[image]

If a user is logged in, the App component receives from my backend's database (inside the 'me' query) the ids of the games in the user's library and, when the user navigates to Library, then those ids are used to fetch games' details from a third party API.

This fetch is currently done with an Apollo useQuery() in `<Library/>`, but that causes the usual `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component` warning when the user logs out and `<Library/>` gets unmounted.

What would be the best place and method to deal with this component's async state? (without Redux). Lift the state up to the App component? Some kind of useEffect in the Library component with useLazyQuery instead of useQuery?

Cheers =)

---

---

Edit: On request, here's a simplified version of the Library component (this one fetches the game ids directly from the backend without requiring the game ids from the me query)

```
const Library = () => {
  const { data: libraryResponse, loading: libraryLoading } = useQuery(
    GET_LIBRARY
  );

  if (libraryLoading) return <FullPageSpinner />;

  const games = libraryResponse?.getLibrary;

  if (!games) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Your library is empty.</div>
        <Link to={'/home'}>Click here to find games!</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <GameList games={games} />;
};
```

---

---

edit2: I can confirm that [using useLazyQuery + useEffect instead of useQuery](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6209#issuecomment-676373050) gets rid of the warning, I'm not sure if this is ideal or intended:

Comment: Unless you need your query on the App component, then it makes sense to just leave it in the `<Library/>`. I'm still not sure what is inside your Library and how it works so if you can provide more code. 

However, seems like a lot of people have been getting this warning. There's a huge thread in github that talks about the exact issue you have.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6209

You can also use useLazyQuery and just call your effect on mount if that works for you

Comment: Thank you, added a simplified version of `<Library/>` =) I'll try with useLazyQuery, but wouldn't uselazyquery's async response cause the same potenial issue it the response arrives after the user logs out and the component is unmounted?

I've seen some fancy solutions for this, such as Kent C Dodd/s useAsync component https://headbutt.io/picking-apart-kents-useasync/,  but they are a bit complicated for my goals, and I was wondering if Apollo provided an easier way.

Comment: I can confirm that using useLazyQuery + useEffect instead of useQuery gets rid of the warning, I'm not sure if this is ideal or intended. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6209#issuecomment-676373050

Comment: Yeah, it seems overly complicated to use the one you've mentioned with useasync since most of what you need is already provided in Apollo